# Dimensionless value to differentiate between concretated and dispersed mass systems

Tags: mass, potential-energy, solar-system, galaxies

I want to find a dimensionless value that differentiates between concentrated mass systems such as the solar system and dispersed mass systems such as a galaxy.

The only value I can think of is the sum of multiplying each mass by its distance, but then I have to normalize this by some mass*distance to make it dimensionless.

Is there any other alternative?

Edit: I assume spherical and radial symmetry, consider both the cases for point masses or smooth mass distributions.

Comment: I think you should think about and express more precisely what you want. Do you assume some sort of spherical or radial symmetry of the system? (I.e. is this only about systems like galaxies and the solar system?) Do you think in terms of point masses or smooth mass distributions? Do you have reference systems that will define what is disperse and what concentrated? (Let's say you find a reasonable value as a characterization, like this sort of "radial center of mass" - normalized by we don't know what - that you are proposing, where will the cutoff value be?)

Comment: I edited the question according to your concerns. I do not want a fixed reference system that defines what is disperse and what is concentrated mass, with no cutoffs.

Comment: Ok, one more problem: Are we dealing with a given system size or is this about accumulations of mass somewhere in space/vacuum? Because a homogeneous cube of metal is a dispersed-mass system, I would say, but a cubic meter of vacuum containing a small metal cube is quite the opposite...

Comment: I want to be able to differentiate between concentrated and dispersed mass systems for any size defined by the space in which the mass is contained. That is, for the size of the solar system and for the size of a galaxy.

Comment: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1954ApJS....1..269N

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a complete answer (or any, maybe), but I'd like to point out that your center-of-mass approach has some disadvantages.

If I understand correctly, your suggestion is to take the radial center of mass and divide it by some product of mass and length. Total mass and system radius spring to mind. Thus given a radial mass density $\rho(r)$ you intend to do something like
$$
\lambda = \frac{\int_0^R r^3 \rho(r) \,\text{d}r}{R\int_0^R r^2 \rho(r) \,\text{d}r}\,.
$$
(Maybe you wanna use $\rho(r)$ instead of $r^2 \rho(r)$ - depending on the definition of $\rho$ and how you deal with the spherical coordinates.)

Let's look at the mass densities $\rho_1(r) = \rho_0 = \text{const}$ and $\rho_2(r) = M \delta\left(r - \frac{3}{4}R\right)$ with $M = \text{const}$. Both yield $\lambda = \frac{3}{4}$, but while I'd consider the first a dispersed-mass system, in the second one the mass is concentrated in a spherical shell. Thus from the value of $\lambda$ we are here unable to decide whether a system has concentrated mass or dispersed mass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the moment I would only want to consider how mass is concentrated towards the center of gravity in the system. Thus, I would consider your case 2 of a shell of a spherical shell of mass also dispersed. 

Is there any other alternative measure of mass dispersion?

Comment: Of course there are alternatives, you could look at the minimal radius $r'$ such that $
\lambda = \frac{\int_0^{r'} r^2 \rho(r) \,\text{d}r}{\int_0^R r^2 \rho(r) \,\text{d}r}\,.
$ is greater than, say 0.8 or some other arbitrary fraction (or, possibly, $r'/R$). Just some random example, you could think of other ways. In any case you'd have to think about where you draw the line between "disperse" and "concentrated". I'm still struggling to not find those terms a bit vague, and depending on their exact meaning there will be better and worse indicators of what is concentrated or disperse.

Comment: But that would mean using a particular radius, which cannot be applied to all systems with different sizes. I want to obtain a dimensionless value using only physical parameters.

Comment: Once we're agreed that each system has a given size/radius $R$ you can use that to make other radii dimensionless... (Like I did in my answer above.)

Comment: If you define a particular value of mass, e.g., that of a galaxy, you are automatically defining a particular radius (the radius which encompass that mass). Defining that radius doesnt bother me since it can always be a variable for which larger values dont change much the dimensionless value im searching for.